# Pandas DataFrame for Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 
from requests import request  
from urllib.request import urlopen  


List_of_FRED_IDs=['CPIAUCSL','A191RL1Q225SBEA','INDPRO']
API_key= "123456789ABCDEFGHIJK"
max_return= 5
def Fred_Values():
    global List_of_FRED_IDs
    Final_Fred_Values={}
    for i in List_of_FRED_IDs:
        final_url= "https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=" + str(i) + "&api_key=" + API_key + "&file_type=json&sort_order=desc&limit="+ str(max_return)
        page = urlopen(final_url)
        data= json.load(page)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data['observations'])
        print(df)

Fred_Values()
```

And it gives me the following output:

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H22bc.png)

How do I set the code up so that:

1. It only gives me the "date" and the "value";
2. I can have the name of the ID in a new column; and
3. It doesn't repeat the header (i.e. realtime_start, realtime_end is printed 3 times)?

I essentially want it to look like this:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcLuo.png)

I cannot figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the output values correctly, something like:

```
def Fred_Values():
    global List_of_FRED_IDs
    Final_Fred_Values={}
    f = []
    for i in List_of_FRED_IDs:
        final_url= "https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=" + str(i) + "&api_key=" + API_key + "&file_type=json&sort_order=desc&limit="+ str(max_return)
        page = urlopen(final_url)
        data= json.load(page)
        f.append(data['observations'])
    return pd.concat(f)
```

Comment: how would use the f.append(data['observations'])? When I run it, it says "NameError: name 'f' is not defined." I am new at Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: I figured what I did wrong above, however, when I put the code in I know get, "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid".. Any ideas?